# How to Iframe google map with PHP

Tags: php, dom, iframe

I'm trying to 'iframe' a div using PHP / DOM instead showing the whole page, but I am having difficulties as the Div contains a custom google map and even when I try to show the entire page I am not able to make the map load. How is it possible to do it?

Link : http://satbeams.com/footprints?beam=5491
Div Id : "map_container"

What I have tried so far :

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('display_errors',false);

include 'includes/dom.php';

$html = file_get_contents('http://satbeams.com/footprints?beam=5491');
$map = $html->find('div[map_container]');
echo $map;

 ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. file_get_contents returns a pure string, not an dom object you may manupilate. So have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php
2. A  Google Map is mainly rendered via a javascript-API, so there isn't any existing iframe in the html markup that you could extract. You would have to parse the json data included in the page, and rebuild the map.
3. Be sure to not violate any copyrights!

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure I will be able to do it with Java. Cheers anyway

Comment: Look at the pages sourcecode in your browser. It only contains:

    <div id="map_container" class="map_container"><div id="map"><div class="load"><div>Loading data. Please wait...</div></div></div></div>

that won't even change, when quering it with java.